# How to do window roll-up/shade in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, window

Does 16.04 include the ability to use the mouse wheel on the title bar to roll the window pane up/down like window blinds/shades?

This is a really handy feature if you have a cluttered screen.

Comment: Nope, Unity doesn't have that feature. Blackbox and Openbox however have it via right click, if you don't mind minimalist desktops

Comment: I've got it in Mint Cinnamon.

Comment: so install cinnamon desktop, its available for Ubuntu too. But default desktop, Unity doesn't have that feature, as i already mentioned

Comment: Well, it is there, but it doesn't quite work properly. If you do Ctrl-Alt-S id does roll up the window, but immediately minimises it to the dock.

Answer (score 1):

Try CCSM compizconfig-settings-manager with it's plugins (via synaptic), there you should find a lot of configuration options including window and mouse behaviour.

Comment: Thanks - I see the "Shade Animation" effect there, but not how to actuate it.

Comment: (Apart from Ctrl-Alt-S, which doesn't quite work.)

Answer (score 1):

**Unity** on 16.04 LTS out-the-box has Window Roll Up / Window Roll Down functionality which is accessed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and set by

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-shaded
['<Primary><Alt>s']
```

User can set middle-click action to shade with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences \
action-middle-click-titlebar 'toggle-shade'
```

But shading seems to be broken on Unity - window shades and then immediately hides in dock. This [bug 1313446](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1313446) is already reported to launchpad.

But these options works better on **GNOME FlashBack Session** which is installed with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

[image: shaded calculator on Xenial]

And of course them work normally on [MATE DE](https://askubuntu.com/a/994001/66509) and Cinnamon.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Unity is running alongside Compiz, you could try to add the following line to ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/Default.ini under '[core]':

s0_toggle_window_shaded_key = w

As you see in the above line, this is supposed to allow you to use w to shade/unshade the focused window.