# MATE 17.10 -- any way to get window shade (roll up) on the window menu

Tags: window, mate, window-manager, menu, ubuntu-mate

This used to be fairly standard - many years ago. I see this:

[How to do window roll-up/shade in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836047/how-to-do-window-roll-up-shade-in-16-04)

But I haven't been able to make any of the solutions work for MATE.

Is there any tweak other than installing an entirely different desktop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to set new window-bar button layout on your Ubuntu MATE

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general button-layout \
'menu,shade:minimize,maximize,close'
```

to get window rolled/unrolled (Roll Up / Roll Down) by mouse

[image: BlackMATE-Roll1]
[image: GreenLaguna-Roll1]

but here exists problem - not all themes support this functionality - at least *BlackMATE*, *GreenLaguna* support it (try from *System->Preferences->Look and Feel->Appearance* or `mate-appearance-properties`).

Other layout is supported by them too as

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general button-layout \
'menu:shade,minimize,maximize,close'
```

[image: BlackMATE-Roll2]
[image: GreenLaguna-Roll2]

You can set keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to change window state:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings toggle-shaded '<Ctrl><Alt>s'
```

Shortcut works even if theme does not show buttons.

Moreover if you want to set shade/unshade on mouse middle-click you do this with:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general action-middle-click-titlebar 'toggle_shade'
```

From  *System->Preferences->Look and Feel->Windows* (`mate-window-properties`) on *Behaviour* tab you can set *Titlebar Action* on double-click on it (*Double-click titlebar to perform this action*) to *Roll up* instead of default *Maximize*.

I hope that finding and [downloading themes](http://mate-desktop.org/themes/) is not a problem.  Two are in the repository - *Numix* (`numix-gtk-theme` package) and *Numix Blue* (`numix-blue-gtk-theme` package).

I tested this on 16.04 LTS, 17.10 (now EOL), 18.04 LTS and 19.04 with Marco and Compiz window managers.

Comment: I had to switch to Black Mate. I'm happy with that.