# Window Roll Up using mouse in Ubuntu MATE 18.04.3

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

How can I use mouse scroll over the titlebar to **Shade/Unshade** or **Roll Up/Down** open windows? My system is **Ubuntu Mate 18.04.3**. And I am using the default desktop environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATE 17.10 -- any way to get window shade (roll up) on the window menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993987/mate-17-10-any-way-to-get-window-shade-roll-up-on-the-window-menu) - here I have explained how to use middle (wheel) click.

Comment: I tried that. No option for mouse wheeling in titlebar

Comment: I tried to find this functionality in GUI and in settings (dconf + gsettings) with no luck too.

Comment: @N0rbert, doesn't Ubuntu Mate come with more than one window manager (WM) and even Compiz? I know OP mentioned wanting to use the "default environment" but could it be possible that the other default WMs provide the facility? I don't currently have a UMate VM to check that.  (Off-topice but in Kubuntu 18.04, it's there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIZaq.png.)

Comment: @DKBose MATE come with Marco, Compton and Compiz. So there may be an option to do what OP need. This need further analysis and testing.